# Meteor: how to set array value, within spacebars, dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, spacebars

I don't really know how to explain this... I have a collection that has an array in it and when I go through it I've been setting colors.[0].imageLink and not changing the [0], but now I'd like that to be dynamic depending on the value of a function (in this case the function is viewIndex).

Works, but isn't dynamic:

```
<h3 class='display-price'>$ {{colors.[0].price}}</h3>
```

What I'd think would work but doesn't:

```
<h3 class='display-price'>$ {{colors.[(viewIndex)].price}}</h3>
```

In the corresponding js file (does return 0):

```
'viewIndex': function() {
  console.log(Template.instance().variation.get());
  return Template.instance().variation.get();
}
```

Comment: Did you try it without the parens? I.e.. `$ {{colors.[viewIndex].price}}`. I don't use Meteor or Spacebars templates so I'm really just guessing.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you're actually trying to do? This is a weird pattern - it's rare to need the index in a display loop to access an element.

Comment: Yes I've tried it without the parenthesis, and with parenthesis, and without brackets - pretty much everything. There are essentially variations of an item that I am trying to be able to change by clicking on a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you are trying to do is to define a `colorPrice` helper that takes `colors` and `viewIndex` as parameters as follows:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  colors() {
    return [
      { price: 1},
      { price: 2},
      { price: 3}
    ];
  },
  viewIndex(){
    return 1;
  },
  colorPrice(colors, viewIndex){
    return colors[viewIndex].price;
  }
});
```

Then, in your template you can use it as follows:

```
<template name="hello">
  ${{ colorPrice colors viewIndex }}
</template>
```

Comment: this wasn't quite dynamic seeing as the values were being passed out of a collection with a varying number of color variations, but it did lead to finding a solution so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So thank you to Kalman for getting me thinking of a dynamic way to do this using more of the javascript! My solution was essentially to use helpers and the "this" keyword by calling helper functions within {{#with item}}, which passed "this" all of the values of the current item it was on, so essentially this became possible:

```
variationImage() {
  return this.colors[Template.instance().variation.get()].imageLink[0];
},
variationLink() {
  return this.colors[Template.instance().variation.get()].referralLink;
},
variationPrice() {
  return this.colors[Template.instance().variation.get()].price;
}
```

And at that point getting those values was as simple as using {{variationPrice}} where I needed the price, etc.

```
{{#with item}}
  <h3 class='display-price'>$ {{variationPrice}}</h3>
{{/with}}
```

And just to add more about how the variations worked each item has a pretty much random number of variations (since we scrape them) so we have to do something along these lines to render how many there are and set which variation you're looking at:

(where colors is an array containing the different color variations of an item)

```
{{#each colors}}
  <option value='{{@index}}'>Variation {{variationIndex @index}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

(helper function)

```
variationIndex(index) {
  return index+1;
}
```

(event function to set variation value)

```
'change .color-variation-select': function(event, template) {
  template.variation.set($(event.target).val());
},
```